# I can't update my 12.04 LTS for Linux

Tags: grub2, apt

If I try to update my 12.04 LTS for Linux Ubuntu I get this message:

```
Could not initialise the package information
An unresolvable problem occurred while initialising the package information.
Please report this bug for the 'update-manager' package and try to include the following error message:
'E:Malformed line 5 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list (dist parse)'
```

How can I solve this problem?

### /etc/apt/sources.list

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security main restricted universe     multiverse
deb http://www.mozilla.org main
deb-src http://www.mozilla.org main
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted universe multiverse
```

Comment: 'E:Malformed line 5 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list (dist parse)` ... see the answer below and check line 5.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by undoing the change you made to sources.list, which broke the file. If you're not quite sure what to change, add the entire file to your question (don't post it as a comment).

Edit after the sources.list was shared:

You will need to remove those bogus mozilla.org lines, they make no sense.

Comment: I never changed the source list. So I can't undo it ... How should the source list look like?

Comment: It doesn't change itself, so something you did must have changed it. The file lives in `/etc/apt/sources.list`. Please add its content to your question.

Comment: I# /etc/apt/sources.list

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://www.mozilla.org main
deb-src http://www.mozilla.org main
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted universe multiverse

Comment: once more ... I opened this: gksudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list    and found this:   # /etc/apt/sources.list

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://www.mozilla.org main
deb-src http://www.mozilla.org main
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted universe multiverse

Comment: Please add the contents to your question, don't add them as comments, that's unreadable.

Comment: Thanks for mailing me the file, I've updated my answer with better instructions.